# Thread extender/nut for basin waste with gap in thread

Tags: plumbing, plumbing-fixture

I just took my basin apart to replace the broken waste only to find the replacement I bought (the only unslotted waste with the click clack mechanism I wanted at a length the same as the old one to reduce the plumbing required)

Is there a part/nut I can buy to deal with the fact that the thread stops 2 inches from the top? (My basin is a about a 0.5 inch thick.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use a piece of tubular material (like a cut section of pipe), along with a couple large washers, as a spacer.